# Vaadin, disable parent window when child popup opened?

Tags: java, user-interface, popup, vaadin

I need to disable the parent window, when a child window popup open. I tried setting the `setEnable(false)` to the Parent window, but, it disable the child as well. Is there any way to disable the parent window only?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is defining the subwindow modal. After setting it to modal your parent window can't be used anymore.

```
Window subwindow = new Window();
subwindow.setModal(true);
```

More information [here](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/application.child-windows.html#application.child-windows.modal).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I want to make the parent window's background in gray color. What is the CSS classes? Is there any default classes?

Comment: have a look at .v-window-modalitycurtain

Answer (score 0):

You can see The Vaadin addon, about name is ConfirmDialog!
I find this is disable the parent window, when a child window popup open.!
I just now start read it!